# finding the distance between a set of points using scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(X, Y) in python

Tags: python, arrays, distance

I have an array of data, called A that looks something like:

```
array([[0.59, 1.23], [0.89, 1.67], [0.21,0.99]...])
```

and has about 400 sets of [x,y] points in it. I want to find the distance between every set of points in A to each sets of points in B, which is another array which looks exactly the same as A but is half the length (So about 200 sets of[x,y] points). So if I wanted to find the distance between the q-th pair of [x,y] values in B against all [x,y] values in A, I've tried doing something along the lines of

```
import scipy.spatial.distance
for q in range(0,len(B)):
    y=scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(A,B[:q,:])
```

but I don't think this is working. I just want an output that shows the distance between the q-th row of B against all points in A.

Comment: Is the resulting matrix too big if you calculate `cdist(A,B)` and then take `y[:,q]` for the distances for q-th item of B?

Comment: that's perfect, thanks! If you want to post as an official answer than I can mark the question as answered :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two solutions:

calculate the complete matrix directly, and the access the q-th column for the values between A and B[q].

```
d = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(A,B)

for q in range(len(B)):
    y = d[:,q]
    print y
```

If the resulting matrix is too big to hold in memory. You could do this.

```
for q in range(len(B)):
    y = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(A,[B[q]])
    print y
```

Comment: Which of the two solutions has less computation time?